# When is best way to open a file to write to?

Tags: python, file, file-writing

Let's say I need to crunch some data and then write the results to some file.

Would it be better to open the file first, then process the data, then write to the file?

```
with open('file', 'w') as f:
    summary = process_data()
    f.write(summary)
```

Or would it be better to open the file just before writing to it?

```
summary = process_data()
with open('file', 'w') as f:
    f.write(summary)
```

My intuition tells me that if `process_data()` requires a lot of memory and if `file` is large, there may be some issues with the first approach.

**Edit:**

To clarify from some of the responses, what are the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: Why not create `summary` before the `with`, then only use the `with` block to do the actual writing?

Comment: Since 2 out of 2 answers down there are talking about using a `with` statement for some weird reason, mind if I rewrite your 2nd code snippet to use a `with`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey just did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn’t have c-like scopes, only scoping constructs are `def` and `class` blocks, so `summary` is not cleaned up after `with` block has ended in the second example.

I can think of only one difference: opening file in a write mode clears it, so if the `process_data` takes a long time inside the `with` block - it leaves file in an empty state for longer.

If that’s not a concern this is 2+3 vs 3+2.

Answer (score 0):

define better...

I can think of a few aspects:

1. Amount of time the file is takes - if this file is needed by other users, it would be best to keep it open for your usage as little as possible --> process before
2. Clean coding - the `with` statement is neater than the `open + close` --> process inside

> My intuition tells me that if process_data() requires a lot of memory and if file is large, there may be some issues with the first approach.

The size of `file` shouldn't matter, as you don't read it, you only open it for writing...